# I want to be able to hold down control by code

Tags: c#, keyboard-hook

I'm using c#, Visual Studio 2010 for a Windows application.

I want to hold down the Ctrl key, then release it after a while.

I tried this but it didnt work.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags,
    UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);

    public const uint KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x02;
    public const uint VK_CONTROL = 0x11;

// Press the Control key.
keybd_event(VK_CONTROL,0,0,0);
//release the control key
keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

But I get this error

The best overloaded method match for 'ImageR.Form1.keybd_event(byte, byte, uint, System.UIntPtr)

cannot convert from 'uint' to 'byte'

cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.UIntPtr'

Comment: Read what you've written. You've declared the function as taking `byte` parameters, but then declared both `KEYEVENTF_KEYUP` and `VK_CONTROL` as type `uint`. As the compiler tells you, `byte != uint`. It's extremely important to learn to *read the actual words in the error message* - they almost always provide information you can use to figure out the problem if you just pay attention to them.

Comment: Also, `keybd_event` is deprecated. Use `SendInput` instead. There are examples here of using it, if you search for `[c#] SendInput` (including the brackets).

Comment: Change it to "public const uint KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x02;
        public const byte VK_CONTROL = 0x11;" still get error ´cannot convert from int to System.UintPtr.

Comment: A quick search here on `[c#] keybd_event` turns up many examples of using this obsolete function. I still highly recommend that you stop trying to use it (again, it's deprecated) and search for examples of `SendInput` instead.

Comment: I give up. :-) I can only repeat "You should look into `SendInput` instead" so many times, and I've even gone to the trouble of finding the search expression for you to use to do so. If you're going to ignore the responses you get, why in the world did you bother to ask the question here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find any good examples of `do SendInput`, the examples at http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.keybd_event didn't work for me.

The best solution to solve this was at http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/

Now it's this simple:

```
//Press Ctrl

InputSimulator.SimulateKeyDown(VirtualKeyCode.CONTROL);

//Release Ctrl

InputSimulator.SimulateKeyUp(VirtualKeyCode.CONTROL);
```